# Sending Json Data to MongoDB Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mongodb, database

i've got a problem which i can't resolve for some time now, i tried to research but nothing comes to my mind.

First of all - This is my app:

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use("/node_modules", express.static('node_modules'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('quotes').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log(req.body)
        console.log('saved to database')
        res.redirect('/')
    })
})

var db
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/db', (err, database) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    db = database
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('listening on 3000')
    })
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/my.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller='PostsCtrl' class='container'>
        <h1>
            <center>Shoutbox</center>
        </h1>
        Your Nick
        <form role='form'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input ng-model="postName" class='form-control'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        Your Shout
        <form role='form'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input ng-model="postBody" class='form-control'>
                    <span class='input-group-btn'>
              <button ng-click='addPost()' class='btn btn-default'>Add Shout</button>
            </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul class='list-group'>
            <li ng-repeat='post in posts' class='list-group-item'>
                <strong>@{{ post.username }}</strong>
                <span>{{ post.body }}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', [])
        app.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

            $scope.addPost = function() {

                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/quotes',
                    data: {
                        "Object": "Value"
                    }
                }).then(function(success) {
                    console.log("sent")
                }, function(error) {
                    cosnole.log(err)
                });

                if ($scope.postBody) {
                    $scope.posts.unshift({
                            username: $scope.postName,
                            body: $scope.postBody
                        }),


                        $scope.postBody = ''
                    $scope.postName = ''
                }
            }

            $scope.posts = []
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html
```

Now here's my problem:

Everything seems to be ok, data is sent but when i'm browsing mongo for entries - only ID is saved, no data whatsoever.

I have no idea where it's going wrong.

This is what's saved to database:

{ _id: 59304d915d20041a272bd96d }

When i manually save json to database - it works ok so i assume thats not problem with mongo itself.

Thanks for every hint you provide.

/edit

Apparently i have resolved the issue by using app.use( bodyParser.json() ); on the server side.

To be closed.

Comment: Can you provide the output of one of the console logs you make in your node code (the one with the request body `console.log(req.body)`). Side-note: you should really consider using semicolons in your js code.

Comment: The output of the console.log you requested is exactly what is saved to database. "{ _id: 59304d915d20041a272bd96d }"

I have cleaned the code a bit, and fixed semilolons.

Comment: Well that would mean that you're not passing the data you want to the ` db.collection('quotes').save`...